# About Child of Animation

Tags: animation

I have a question about Child of.
I would like to create an animation in which an object is held from the left hand to the right hand and then released at the end, but I cannot get the Child of to transfer to the right hand.
(1) Set the target to the left hand bone.
(2) Set the influence of the left hand to 0 and let it influence the right hand.
(3) Set the influence of both hands to 0 and hit the keyframe.

I am thinking of the above procedure
I am thinking that perhaps the set inverse etc. is different.
Please let me know if you know anything about this.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can see what you have done and verify our solution proposals, thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dynamic Parent addon](https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent/releases/tag/v1.0.0) by Roman Volodin, it will automatize the following process, or you can do it manually:

Give a *Child Of* constraint to your object with the first bone as *Target*, click on the *Set Inverse* button so that the object doesn't move away:

[image]

Keyframe your bone 1 so that it moves towards bone 2, let's say that the last frame of the first movement is frame 20, also keyframe the *Locrotscale* of the object:

[image]

At the next frame, here frame 21, when the second bone is supposed to take control, keyframe the object's *Visual Locrotscale*, don't pay attention to the fact that it will move away:

[image]

Give the object a second *Child Of* with the second bone as *Target*, click on the *Set Inverse* button, at frame 20 keyframe the *Influence* of the first *Child Of* at 1, and the *Influence* of the second *Child Of* at 0, at frame 21, do the inverse:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: >>monnboots san

Thank you for the instruction on the two ways to do this!
I tried both and both worked.
The add on is also useful and I will use it depending on the situation.
Very helpful and informative!